# How can I have same XML element order as defined in JAXB class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am generating a XML file for a given class. But the elements are getting generating in alphabetical order, not in the order of their declaration. Class has around 40 elements so *@XmlType(propOrder ={})* is not going to be useful. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no way to generate an XML file for a given class following the order of declaration, without using @XmlType(propOrder={}).

The alphabetical ordering may be caused by the default behavior of @XmlAccessorOrder in your JAXB implementation, that may be set on XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL. You can change it by annotating your class with :

```
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessType.UNDEFINED)
```

But the order will be dependent on the system’s reflection implementation, and may not give you what you wish for.

It might be a bit annoying to list 40 elements in the propOrder, but it's the correct way to do it.

Source : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnbcz/index.html

Comment: Actually I didn't require elements in some defined order. Xml was parsed perfectly irrespective of the order of elements. Still thanks

Comment: Small correction: it should be `@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.UNDEFINED)`. Unfortunately, this seems to be the default, so including it didn't make any difference in my case; still alphabetical...